# How to create a new column to store the length of a linestring in postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgis-1.5, length

I am working with pgRouting, following this nice guide：[A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/)

I am now in this step：Calculating shortest routes, with these codes below

```
SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
SELECT gid AS id, 
      start_id::int4 AS source, 
      end_id::int4 AS target, 
      shape_leng::float8 AS cost
FROM network',
1,
5110,
false,
false);
```

and my network table looks like this
[image]

apparently I have no column "shape_leng", so I need to create a new column in table network, and it is the length of every row.

But I don't know how I should type the ST_length code.

Can someone give me some advice？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use following sql.

```
ALTER TABLE network ADD COLUMN shape_leng double precision;
UPDATE network SET shape_leng = length(the_geom);
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 4):

If the data in the `network` table is either being updated or added, it would be wise to make a [trigger function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) to update the data, so the line lengths are always up-to-date. To do this, make a trigger procedure, written in PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shape_leng() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  NEW.shape_leng := ST_Length(NEW.the_geom);
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(note, I use the `ST_Length` PostGIS function, but it can be swapped out with other methods.) Then make the trigger fire on the `network` table for insert and update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER network_shape_leng
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON network
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE shape_leng();
```

Play around with the data, and you will see it automatically fill this value in for you. Similar triggers can be built for shape area (for polygons).